# Convert from #define to string c++

Tags: c++, string, c-preprocessor

I would like to convert from #define to string.

My code:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#define PREFIX_PATH = "..\\"
#else
#define PREFIX_PATH = "..\\..\\"
#endif


#define VAL(str) #str
#define TOSTRING(str) VAL(str)

string prefix = TOSTRING(PREFIX_PATH);
string path = prefix + "Test\\Input\input.txt";
```

But, it didn't work..

prefix value is "..\\\"

Any idea what is the problem..

Thanks!

Comment: Is this work `string prefix = PREFIX_PATH;`

Comment: `string prefix = PREFIX_PATH;`

Comment: `PREFIX_PATH` is already defined as a quoted string, but it is passed through `VAL`, which tries to quote the symbol again, with `#`.  Also, note that non-Windows OS's usually use forward slashes, not backslashes as a path separator.

Comment: Your macro definitions are wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need "=" in defines, or any #str, or "+" between double quoted strings.

```
#ifdef WIN32
    #define PREFIX_PATH "..\\"
#else
    #define PREFIX_PATH "..\\..\\"
#endif

string path = PREFIX_PATH "Test\\Input\\input.txt";
```

Answer (score 7):

What about something simpler like that?

```
#ifdef WIN32
const std::string prefixPath = "..\\";
#else
const std::string prefixPath = "..\\..\\";
#endif

std::string path = prefixPath + "Test\\Input\\input.txt";
```

**PS** You may have a typo in the last line, in which you may miss another `\` before `input.txt`.

As an alternative, if your C++ compiler supports this C++11 feature, you may want to use **raw string literals**, so you can have unescaped `\`, e.g.:

```
std::string path = prefixPath + R"(Test\Input\input.txt)";
```

Comment: _"which I almost copied-and-pasted from your question"_ Almost? That's exactly what you've done :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Not exactly, note the `prefixPath` instead of just `prefix` :)

Answer (score 2):

Although I'd highly recommend Mr.C64's approach, but if you want to use define for some reason then,

```
#ifdef WIN32
    #define PREFIX_PATH "..\\"
#else
    #define PREFIX_PATH "..\\..\\"
#endif

std::string prefix = PREFIX_PATH;
std::string path = PREFIX_PATH + "Test\\Input\\input.txt";
```

For #define you don't put an equals between key and value, and the TOSTRING function was unnecessary. #define is just find-replace so thinking in those terms might help you use it.